# Does the Tanach ever use letters for numbers?

Tags: tanach

Does the Tanach ever use letters for numbers?

For example it says אַרְבָּעָה מְלָכִים   i.e. 4/four kings.. but it doesn't say it as 
ד מְלָכִים   it uses the word for four (arba/arbaah), but not the letter dalet.

Comment: The closest I can think of is letters for objects ווי העמודים

Comment: @Heshy That's Ex 38:10, are you really saying that the vavs there in Ex 38:10 are shaped like pegs reflecting the meaning of the word?

Comment: The answer is no. There is no such thing in tanach!

Comment: Exactly.  It's the only noun in Tanach (besides the occasional name ופסי ושתי ויזתא) that starts with a vav, and I've heard it argued that the hooks got that name because they're shaped like the letter.  (Note the letter looks kind of like a hook in Ktav Ivri too, so you don't have to get into that whole topic.)

Comment: @Heshy וְהִתְוִיתָ תָּו

Comment: @Bach is it mishnaic?

Comment: There's "chet hameraglim" ח' המרגלים...

Comment: Sometimes a Gematria is hinted at.

Comment: @Harel13 I don't see what you are talking about. Hameraglim  occurs only in joshua 6:22 and 6:23  and there's no chet.

Comment: @barlop sorry, it was a joke...I'll just erase that comment I guess...the idea being that חטא and ח' sound the same...also, only afterwards did I realize that the term chet hameraglim doesn't appear in the Torah...